CSP directive blocking style src to load in react js mantine
I'm using mantine version 6.0.13 and vite
I'm facing issue after applying the CSP directive in header, mentioned below
CSP"Content-Security-Policy","default-src http://localhost; style-src 'self' 'nonce-rAnd0m123' http://localhost; font-src 'self';"

Issue
Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
"style-src 'self' 'nonce-rAnd0m123' http://localhost".
Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash, or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. 
Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: 
navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.

We have not used any inline styles src in my code, but still getting the above mentioned error, might it looks like mantine creating internally a inline style src
Please provide some suggestion to fix this issue or any workaround.
I tried inline_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false but not work for me, because I'm not using react-script

If you're not using inline styles, 3rd party scripts could be injecting them. Check the code link in the error. If there are a limited amount of styles being inserted you could allow them with hashes and possibly unsafe hashes. If you lock down the rest of your CSP you can use 'unsafe-inline' as the impact of unsafe styles would be minimal, see https://scotthelme.co.uk/can-you-get-pwned-with-css/
